# Google Chart Color individual Bars

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have used all the tricks in the box. After reading through all the help articles I found i thought this code should actually work. But it never colorcodes my bars. What am I doing wrong?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDualX);

function drawDualX() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Elevation', {
      role: 'style'
    }],
    ['2016-08-06T08:09:47Z', 1977.4, 'color: yellow'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:13:29Z', 1981, 'color: green'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:08Z', 1986.9, 'color: yellow'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:22Z', 1988.9, 'color: green'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:25Z', 1989.2, 'color: green'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:29Z', 1989.7, 'color: yellow'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:32Z', 1990.1, 'color: green'],
  ]);
  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Elevation Chart',
    },
    bars: 'vertical'
  };
 
 
  var material = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  material.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: [here is a better explanation of your options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771) -- if you want an _actual Material chart_ (`.Bar`) -- see Chart 4 -- just need to convert rows to columns then use the `colors` configuration option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this is not working is because the `google.charts.Bar(...)` object that you are creating is what Google calls a *Material Chart*. This is a completely redesigned implementation of the Google Visualization API, distinct from what they call the "Classic" chart packages and this still currently in beta. There are a number of related questions on here (see below) and it appears that column roles (as you have used here to designate `'color'`) are not yet supported for *Material Charts*.

If you want to use customised styles for each data point, you have to use the older (but much better supported) Google Visualization "Classic" corechart package as follows. The initial design of the chart is a bit different, but the more extensive customization options should mean that you can get it to look how you want!

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart' /*, 'bar'*/ ] /* Don't need to load the bar package */
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDualX);

function drawDualX() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Elevation', {
      role: 'style'
    }],
    ['2016-08-06T08:09:47Z', 1977.4, 'color: yellow'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:13:29Z', 1981, 'color: green'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:08Z', 1986.9, 'color: yellow'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:22Z', 1988.9, 'color: green'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:25Z', 1989.2, 'color: green'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:29Z', 1989.7, 'color: yellow'],
    ['2016-08-06T08:14:32Z', 1990.1, 'color: green'],
  ]);
  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Elevation Chart',
    },
    //bars: 'vertical' /* This option isn't required for "Classic" column chart */
  };

  /* Create a "Classic" Google Visualization Column Chart */
  var material = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  material.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

[Related SO question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551531/google-material-chart-column-chart-bar-chart-custom-column-color-not-working?rq=1)

[Related SO question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213575/rendering-a-google-line-chart-curvetype-not-setting-and-animation-not-working-a/39225874#39225874)

Answer (score 0):

If you want [Bar Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) to be vertical, use [Column Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).
Horizontal version of column chart is bar chart.

Try this

```js
 google.charts.load("current", {
   packages: ['corechart']
 });
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDualX);

 function drawDualX() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Elevation', {
      role: 'style'
    }],
    ["2016-08-06T08:09:47Z", 1977.4, "color: yellow"],
    ["2016-08-06T08:13:29Z", 1981, "color: green"],
    ["2016-08-06T08:14:08Z", 1986.9, "color: yellow"],
    ["2016-08-06T08:14:22Z", 1988.9, "color: green"],
    ["2016-08-06T08:14:25Z", 1989.2, "color: green"],
    ["2016-08-06T08:14:29Z", 1989.7, "color: yellow"],
    ["2016-08-06T08:14:32Z", 1990.1, "color: green"],
   ]);

   var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
   view.setColumns([0, 1, {
       calc: "stringify",
       sourceColumn: 1,
       type: "string",
       role: "annotation"
     },
     2
   ]);

   var options = {
     title: "Elevation Chart",
     width: 600,
     height: 400,
     bar: {
       groupWidth: "95%"
     },
     legend: {
       position: "none"
     },
   };
   var material = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
   material.draw(view, options);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div">
</div>
```